# Recommended code style: case object Foo or object Foo extends Serializable?

Tags: scala, serialization, object, singleton, language-design

If I want a serialization-safe singleton, should I prefer

```
case object Foo
```

or

```
object Foo extends Serializable
```

?

Comment: How is that a style question? The two code samples do different things!

Comment: The two are *not* equivalent.

Comment: I have never claimed that they are equivalent, both just add the same code for serialization to the bytecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this depends on how you plan to use this object.  Case objects are generally used with case classes to represent some kind of initial or terminal object in an algebraic data type, eg `Nil` or `None`.  Regular objects usually are companions for classes to hold static methods like singleton and factory methods.

If you're planning using this object with other classes, serializing it, and maybe using it in pattern matching, defining it as a case object seems more natural to me.